NextJS 15 - import a localFont with multiple sources only once
I found out using create-next-app that the best practice to load a localFont and pass it to all our component was to load it from the top layout.js like this:
const geistSans = localFont({
  src: "./fonts/GeistVF.woff",
  variable: "--font-geist-sans",
  weight: "100 900",
});

and then pass the variable through the body classes:
<body className={`${geistSans.variable} antialiased`}>
  {children}
</body>

Allowing me to use it from anywhere like so:
<p className="font-[family-name:var(--font-geist-sans)]">Hi StackOverflow</p>

Now, I would like to load multiple weight of the same font into the same variable (if possible) but I'm struggling to understand how to then pass it to all the children of my top layout.
const mPlus = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: "./fonts/MPLUSRounded1cBold.ttf",
      weight: "700",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/MPLUSRounded1c.ttf",
      weight: "400",
      style: "normal",
    },
  ],
});

But I struggle to find out, how I am supposed to pass this new loaded font and re-use it and fails to find any hints on the documentation.
Any of you have a recommendation or could give me a lead on how to approach that?
If they are better approach, please let me know ‍♂️
Thank you in advance 

Answering my own question:
If you want to use multiple sources you still need to have one variable field into such as:
const mPlus = localFont({
  variable: "--font-mplus",
  src: [
    {
      path: "./fonts/MPLUSRounded1cBold.ttf",
      weight: "700",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/MPLUSRounded1c.ttf",
      weight: "400",
      style: "normal",
    },
  ],
});

and should be pass via the body the same way, then the right font will be loaded depending on if you use font-bold or not.
